# Table of Chebyshev's Theta Function for Large-ish Values of x?

Tags: number-theory, chebyshev-function

Chebyshev's Theta Function is defined as $\vartheta(x)=\sum_{p\le x} \log p$

I am trying to find a table of this function for large-ish values of $x$, preferably in a form I could download to a spreadsheet. By "large-ish" I mean for $x$ over 16000.

I have found a table in a 1962 paper by J.Rosser and L.Schoenfeld, titled "Approximate Formulas for Some Functions of Prime Numbers". Page 91 lists values of  $\vartheta(x)$ for $x$ from 500 to 16000 in steps of 500. My search has not turned up any similar table thus far.

If anyone knows of such a table I would be grateful for the reference.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy enough to compute with a computer algebra system.
For example, in Maple:

```
Primes:= select(isprime,[$1..30000]):
Theta:= x -> convert(map(evalf@ln,select(`<=`,Primes,x)),`+`);
for i from 16000 by 1000 to 30000 do
  print(i,Theta(i))
od:

                   16000, 15886.79251
                   17000, 16838.47253
                   18000, 17854.57508
                   19000, 18777.95241
                   20000, 19805.30968
                   21000, 20778.19314
                   22000, 21815.61079
                   23000, 22817.63579
                   24000, 23864.33160
                   25000, 24814.24553
                   26000, 25808.63562
                   27000, 26837.34886
                   28000, 27798.29406
                   29000, 28803.55793
                   30000, 29750.34194
```

(the last 3 digits or so of each of these may be off due to roundoff error).

Comment: Thanks Robert. That is exactly what I was looking for. Clearly I need to buy some computer algebra software.